# Vue.js - best way to set background image through filter

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js. On my site I have same images in two formats - jpg and webp. I want to generate correct image links depends on browser support (with or without .webp at end) through some filter. I do not need make this detection now, I just want to know what is the best way to set "background-image" and img "src" in Vue.

This is what I have now:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + webp('/images/demo.jpg') + ')' }">
            <div class="container" style="min-height: 520px">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card card-default">
                            <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img v-bind:src="'/images/demo2.jpg' | webp">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        methods: {
            webp(url) {
                // here will be code to detect webp support
                return url + '.webp';
            }
        },

        filters: {
            webp(url) {
                // here will be code to detect webp support
                return url + '.webp';
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

And It works, but it is correct approach? First problem is that I tried to use filter because it looks more clean to me. In img src it works, but in v-bind:style I had to use method. Now in script I have separate method and filter that does the same, that's bad... I tried to use filter but this doesn't work:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + '/images/bg.jpg' | webp + ')' }">
```

I do not need to change image dynamically, so I tried also make it with standard style and use mustache:

```
<div style="background-image: url({{ '/images/bg.jpg' | webp }} ">
```

but this causes "Interpolation inside attributes has been removed."

What is the best, correct and clean way to achieve this, so I can use my webp detection as well in background-image and img src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve your problem,
change the template like this:

```
<div class="invite-container" :style="{backgroundImage: `url(${someBackgroundUrl})`} | imageFilter">
```

In the function `imageFilter(value)`, `value` is an Object, which is `{backgroundImage: "url(https://somesite.com/img.png)"}`

You can detect `webp` support first,  and since you have the image url string, you could change the image format to `webp` now.

Finally, return an Object which is `webp` format. e.g `{backgroundImage: "url(https://somesite.com/img.png/webp)"}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you but I thought the way that [this Kirby CMS plugin](https://github.com/S1SYPHOS/kirby-webp) deals with WebP was clever - it detects WebP support in the server config and redirects any requests to `*.jpg` to `*.webp`. This example is for Apache but it should be possible to take the same approach with other server types.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Checking for WebP browser support ..
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

  # .. and if there's a WebP version for the requested image
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

  # Well, then go for it & serve WebP instead
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That is cool, but first of all I want to learn vue.js :P Also I don't have every image in webp (for example uploaded by users are original), so I want to be specific what files I want to filter.